# Use different color for moderncv subsections

Tags: color, moderncv

I have made color style like below for moderncv. The color1 is used for all sections and subsections I want to use the newly added color3 for subsections instead of color1. How could I do it?

```
\begin{filecontents*}{moderncvcolorteal.sty}
% start of file 'moderncvcolorteal.sty'.

% identification
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesPackage{moderncvcolorteal}[2013/02/09 v1.3.0 modern curriculum vitae and letter color scheme: teal]

% color scheme definition
\definecolor{color0}{rgb}{0,0,0}            % black
\definecolor{color1}{rgb}{0,0.5,0.5}        % teal
\definecolor{color2}{rgb}{0.45,0.45,0.45}   % dark grey
\definecolor{color3}{rgb}{0.56,0,0.13}      % burgundy
\endinput

% end of file 'moderncvcolorteal.sty'.
\end{filecontents*}
```

Comment: Try using the `xpatch` package.

Comment: Would you explain more??

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The coloring of the `\subsection` is defined in the respective `moderncvstyle*.sty` files.

Use e.g.

```
\renewcommand*{\subsectionstyle}[1]{{\subsectionfont\textcolor{color3}{#1}}}
```

to change the subsection color to `color3`.